# Oracle Error PLS-00323: subprogram

Tags: oracle, plsql

The error I have is the following:

> ORA-06550: Encountered the symbol "" when expecting one of the following:;"

```
create or replace PACKAGE BODY ALERTASNOTIFICACIONES AS
     PROCEDURE diferidos AS  
         v_diferido aftdalsa%ROWTYPE;
         v_aux varchar2(1000);
     begin
         v_aux :='UPDATE aftdalsa 
                    set aftdalsa.alsadife = 0 
                     where alsadife = 1 
                     and aftdalsa.alsafeal <= sysdate';
        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE v_aux;
    EXCEPTION
        WHEN OTHERS
        THEN dbms_output.put_line(SQLCODE);
    END diferidos;

 END;
```

Can anybody help me with that? thanks

Comment: Is this all code? Because it compiles successful, and procedure executed without errors.

Comment: @Seyran It will always execute without errors as the exception handling block `EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN` will catch all exceptions and handle them. The OP is presumably getting an output via `DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE` with the error code.

Comment: @MT0, I know, when I wrote  "executed without errors.", I mean what exception block didn't fire, and any output written.

Comment: @OldProgrammer can you tell Oracle version and IDE where you create this code.

Comment: So is your error _PLS-00323 subprogram or cursor xyz is declared in package specification and must be defined in the package body_ as suggested in the question title, or _ORA-06550: Encountered the symbol "" when expecting one of the following:;"_ as mentioned above? I can't see how it could be both.

Answer (score -1):

You should not need dynamic SQL for your procedure:

```
create or replace PACKAGE BODY ALERTASNOTIFICACIONES AS
  PROCEDURE diferidos
  AS  
  begin
    UPDATE aftdalsa
    SET    alsadife = 0
    WHERE  alsadife = 1
    AND    alsafeal <= sysdate;
  END diferidos;
END;
/
```